# StatefulSet FailedCreate ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

When attempting to install ElasticSearch for Kubernetes on a PKS instance I am running into an issue where after running `kubectl get events --all-namespaces` I see `create Pod logging-es-default-0 in StatefulSet logging-es-default failed error: pods "logging-es-default-0" is forbidden: SecurityContext.RunAsUser is forbidden`. Does this have something to do with a pod security policy? Is there any way to be able to deploy ElasticSearch to Kubernetes if privileged containers are not allowed?

Edit: here is the values.yml file that I am passing into the elasticsearch helm chart.

```
---
clusterName: "elasticsearch"
nodeGroup: "master"

# The service that non master groups will try to connect to when joining the cluster
# This should be set to clusterName + "-" + nodeGroup for your master group
masterService: ""

# Elasticsearch roles that will be applied to this nodeGroup
# These will be set as environment variables. E.g. node.master=true
roles:
  master: "true"
  ingest: "true"
  data: "true"

replicas: 3
minimumMasterNodes: 2

esMajorVersion: ""

# Allows you to add any config files in /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/
# such as elasticsearch.yml and log4j2.properties
esConfig: {}
#  elasticsearch.yml: |
#    key:
#      nestedkey: value
#  log4j2.properties: |
#    key = value

# Extra environment variables to append to this nodeGroup
# This will be appended to the current 'env:' key. You can use any of the kubernetes env
# syntax here
extraEnvs: []
#  - name: MY_ENVIRONMENT_VAR
#    value: the_value_goes_here

# A list of secrets and their paths to mount inside the pod
# This is useful for mounting certificates for security and for mounting
# the X-Pack license
secretMounts: []
#  - name: elastic-certificates
#    secretName: elastic-certificates
#    path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs

image: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch"
imageTag: "7.4.1"
imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"

podAnnotations: {}
  # iam.amazonaws.com/role: es-cluster

# additionals labels
labels: {}

esJavaOpts: "-Xmx1g -Xms1g"

resources:
  requests:
    cpu: "100m"
    memory: "2Gi"
  limits:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "2Gi"

initResources: {}
  # limits:
  #   cpu: "25m"
  #   # memory: "128Mi"
  # requests:
  #   cpu: "25m"
  #   memory: "128Mi"

sidecarResources: {}
  # limits:
  #   cpu: "25m"
  #   # memory: "128Mi"
  # requests:
  #   cpu: "25m"
  #   memory: "128Mi"

networkHost: "0.0.0.0"

volumeClaimTemplate:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 30Gi

rbac:
  create: false
  serviceAccountName: ""

podSecurityPolicy:
  create: false
  name: ""
  spec:
    privileged: false
    fsGroup:
      rule: RunAsAny
    runAsUser:
      rule: RunAsAny
    seLinux:
      rule: RunAsAny
    supplementalGroups:
      rule: RunAsAny
    volumes:
      - secret
      - configMap
      - persistentVolumeClaim

persistence:
  enabled: true
  annotations: {}

extraVolumes: ""
  # - name: extras
  #   emptyDir: {}

extraVolumeMounts: ""
  # - name: extras
  #   mountPath: /usr/share/extras
  #   readOnly: true

extraInitContainers: ""
  # - name: do-something
  #   image: busybox
  #   command: ['do', 'something']

# This is the PriorityClass settings as defined in
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#priorityclass
priorityClassName: ""

# By default this will make sure two pods don't end up on the same node
# Changing this to a region would allow you to spread pods across regions
antiAffinityTopologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"

# Hard means that by default pods will only be scheduled if there are enough nodes for them
# and that they will never end up on the same node. Setting this to soft will do this "best effort"
antiAffinity: "hard"

# This is the node affinity settings as defined in
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity-beta-feature
nodeAffinity: {}

# The default is to deploy all pods serially. By setting this to parallel all pods are started at
# the same time when bootstrapping the cluster
podManagementPolicy: "Parallel"

protocol: http
httpPort: 9200
transportPort: 9300

service:
  labels: {}
  labelsHeadless: {}
  type: ClusterIP
  nodePort: ""
  annotations: {}
  httpPortName: http
  transportPortName: transport

updateStrategy: RollingUpdate

# This is the max unavailable setting for the pod disruption budget
# The default value of 1 will make sure that kubernetes won't allow more than 1
# of your pods to be unavailable during maintenance
maxUnavailable: 1

podSecurityContext:
  fsGroup: null
  runAsUser: null

# The following value is deprecated,
# please use the above podSecurityContext.fsGroup instead
fsGroup: ""

securityContext:
  capabilities: null
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  runAsNonRoot: null
  runAsUser: null

# How long to wait for elasticsearch to stop gracefully
terminationGracePeriod: 120

sysctlVmMaxMapCount: 262144

readinessProbe:
  failureThreshold: 3
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  successThreshold: 3
  timeoutSeconds: 5

# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html#request-params wait_for_status
clusterHealthCheckParams: "wait_for_status=green&timeout=1s"

## Use an alternate scheduler.
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/
##
schedulerName: ""

imagePullSecrets: []
nodeSelector: {}
tolerations: []

# Enabling this will publically expose your Elasticsearch instance.
# Only enable this if you have security enabled on your cluster
ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  path: /
  hosts:
    - chart-example.local
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local

nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

# https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/issues/63
masterTerminationFix: false

lifecycle: {}
  # preStop:
  #   exec:
  #     command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello from the postStart handler > /usr/share/message"]
  # postStart:
  #   exec:
  #     command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello from the postStart handler > /usr/share/message"]

sysctlInitContainer:
  enabled: false

keystore: []
```

The values listed above produce the following error:

```
create Pod elasticsearch-master-0 in StatefulSet elasticsearch-master failed error: pods "elasticsearch-master-0" is forbidden: SecurityContext.RunAsUser is forbidden
```

Solved: I learned that my istio deployment was causing issues when attempting to deploy any other service into my cluster. I had made a bad assumption that istio along with my cluster security policies weren't causing my issue.

Comment: same issue did you find a workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is forbidden: `SecurityContext.RunAsUser` is forbidden. Does this have something to do with a pod security policy?

Yes, that's exactly what it has to do with

Evidently the `StatefulSet` has included a `securityContext:` stanza, but your cluster administrator forbids such an action

> Is there any way to be able to deploy ElasticSearch to Kubernetes if privileged containers are not allowed?

That's not exactly what's going on here -- it's not the "privileged" part that is causing you problems -- it's the `PodSpec` requesting to run the container as a user other than the one in the docker image. In fact, I would actually be very surprised if any modern elasticsearch docker image requires modifying the user at all, since all the recent ones do not run as `root` to begin with

Remove that `securityContext:` stanza from the `StatefulSet` and report back what new errors arise (if any)

Comment: I updated the `securityContext` for the `StatefulSet`. Seems like it got one step further, now running into `create Pod elasticsearch-master-0 in StatefulSet elasticsearch-master failed error: Pod "elasticsearch-master-0" is invalid: spec.initContainers[0].securityContext.privileged: Forbidden: disallowed by cluster policy`. I can ascertain that this relates to the security context for the init containers. I am going to try to run it with `privileged: false` in that specific security context.

Comment: So ran into a little bit of an issue with trying to disable the privileged access, it is hardcoded in the helm template: https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/master/elasticsearch/templates/statefulset.yaml. Any ideas on if that is the right rabbit hole to jump down or could there be something else to try first?

Comment: It is not hardcoded, it is [guarded by `sysctlInitContainer.enabled`](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/7.4.1/elasticsearch/templates/statefulset.yaml#L135); that container is optional and is designed just to [exec a `sysctl`](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/7.4.1/elasticsearch/templates/statefulset.yaml#L141) on its Node, so you can contact the cluster admin and request that sysctl already have the correct value for the Nodes you're going to run ES upon, then you don't need the `initContainer`

Comment: I went ahead and disabled the init container and received the new error that I put in the edit of my post. Any thoughts?

Comment: I did resolve it by updating the values to the following and packaged elasticsearch (helm package elasticsearch) locally:
```runAsUser:1000
privileged: false```